# AppEnginePlatformWarning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App Engine sandbox instead of sockets

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, slack-api

I'm getting this error on app engine using flask to make a Slack bot.  It happens whenever I send a POST request from Slackbot.

Unfortunately, the url provided in the error is a dead link.  How do I go about using sockets instead of URLFetch?

> /base/data/home/apps/[REDACTED]/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py:115:
>   AppEnginePlatformWarning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App
>   Engine sandbox instead of sockets. To use sockets directly instead of
>   URLFetch see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html.

Comment: Here's the correct URL: http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html

Answer (score 7):

As detailed on [Google's Sockets documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/), sockets can be used by setting the `GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB` environment variable. This feature seems to be available only on paid apps, and impacts billing.

Though the error you posted gets logged as an Error in App Engine, [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1481) suggests (see reply #8) that the error is actually meant as a warning, which the text "AppEnginePlatformWarning" seems to suggest anyway.

The comment block on the [source page](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py) for appengine.py is also instructive.

You didn't post any information about your implementation, but on Google App Engine Standard edition, [using URLFetch via the AppEngineManager should be just fine](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html), though you will get the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to silence this:

```
import warnings
import urllib3.contrib.appengine

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r'urllib3 is using URLFetch', urllib3.contrib.appengine.AppEnginePlatformWarning)
```

Comment: where can I put this?
I am using a library that does this from within. Do I need to edit the library's source?

Comment: @divij put it near the beginning of your `main()` function or just before you call the library for the first time. It will apply to everything in your program until it exits.

Comment: Okay I will try that!

Comment: just in case - you can add this to appengine_config.py to ignore the warning
`import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r'urllib3')`

Answer (score 1):

For me, turns out the presence of requests_toolbelt dependency in my project was the problem: it *somehow* forced the requests library to use urllib3, which requires URLFetch to be  present, otherwise it [raises an AppEnginePlatformError](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html). As suggested in [the app engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests), monkey-patching Requests with requests_toolbelt forces the former to use URLFetch, which is no [longer supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#url_fetch) by GAE in a Python 3 runtime.

The solution was to remove `requests_toolbelt` from my `requirements.txt` file