# AppEnginePlatformWarning - reason to use sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, google-app-engine, python-requests

In the Google App Engine standard environment, if you use urllib to make HTTPS requests, you'll get an `AppEnginePlatformWarning` which says you're using urlfetch instead of sockets.

I found the warning annoying, so I disabled it.

```
# Use the App Engine Requests adapter. This makes sure that Requests uses
# URLFetch.
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

# squelch warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine.AppEnginePlatformWarning
)
```

My question is - is there a good reason to switch to sockets? Specifically what is wrong with using urlfetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `urlfetch`, in fact it is the recommended method for issuing outbound HTTP(S) requests on GAE. From [Issuing HTTP(S) Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests) (emphasis on `requests`-related note mine):

> App Engine uses the URL Fetch service to issue outbound HTTP(S)
>   requests.
>
> For details about how the URL Fetch service is implemented and which
>   headers are sent in a URL Fetch request, see [Outbound Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests).
>
> Issuing an HTTP request
>
> To issue an outbound HTTP request, use the [`urlfetch.fetch`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch)
>   method. For improved code portability, you can also use the Python
>   standard libraries `urllib`, `urllib2`, or `httplib` to issue HTTP
>   requests. When you use these libraries in App Engine, they perform
>   HTTP requests using App Engine's URL Fetch service. **You can also use
>   the third-party `requests` library as long as you configure it to use
>   URLFetch.**

The sockets support is rather the problematic one in GAE, it comes with a fairly long list of limitations and restrictions, see [Sockets Python API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/), in particular the [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif) section.

The warning you see is not from GAE, it's from the 3rd-party `requests` library you use, which is why I highlighted the note in the above quote. IMHO it's safe to simply ignore/mask the warning in a GAE context.

Comment: The warning was made explicitly for App Engine, which is what is confusing. It's actually coming from urllib3, not requests. Requests simply packages it within itself.